# Toolbar in Angular change the style of my Login

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I have a problem with my final paper assignment. I have an Angular project with a Login component and was trying not to show the toolbar (another component) when the system does not have a currentUser. Well, I managed to get to the result using `<ng-content></ng-content>` in the Toolbar, but the Login style changes when I do it this way.

**login.component.html**

```
<div class="logo">
    <a href="https://www.cedupcriciuma.com.br/" target="_blank"><img class="iconLogo"
            src="../../../../assets/LogoCedup.png" alt="Logo"></a>
</div>
<div class="spinnerDiv">
    <svg class="spinnerBar" *ngIf="loading" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="42" />
    </svg>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="containerText">
        <h1 class="textImportant">O novo portal do <span>CooperCedup</span>, trazendo ainda mais confiança para seus
            alunos!</h1>
        <h3 class="textSub">Mais simples, prático e moderno. A cara do nosso CEDUP.</h3>
    </div>

    <div> <img class="flatImage" src="../../../../assets/imageDocument.svg" alt="Imagem simples de um documento"> </div>
    <mat-card>
        <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <mat-card-content>
                <div>
                    <h1 mat-form-title>
                        <b class="loginText">Login</b>
                    </h1>
                    <br>
                    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                        <mat-label>Matrícula</mat-label>
                        <input formControlName="login" matInput placeholder="" required maxlength="20">
                        <button mat-icon-button matSuffix>
                            <mat-icon>face</mat-icon>
                        </button>

                    </mat-form-field>
                    <br>

                    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                        <mat-label>Senha</mat-label>
                        <input formControlName="password" matInput [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'" required
                            maxlength="11">
                        <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide" [attr.aria-label]="'Hide password'"
                            [attr.aria-pressed]="hide">
                            <mat-icon>{{hide ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
                        </button>
                        <mat-hint align="end"><u><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffc107;">Esqueci
                                    minha senha</a></u></mat-hint>

                    </mat-form-field>

                    <br>

                </div>
                <br>
            </mat-card-content>
            <button type="submit" (click)="loadingSpinner()" class="loginButton">Entrar</button>

            <!--(click)="Submit()"-->
            <mat-card-actions>
            </mat-card-actions>
        </form>
    </mat-card>
</div>

<div class="shape">
    <svg data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 120" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <path
            d="M0,0V46.29c47.79,22.2,103.59,32.17,158,28,70.36-5.37,136.33-33.31,206.8-37.5C438.64,32.43,512.34,53.67,583,72.05c69.27,18,138.3,24.88,209.4,13.08,36.15-6,69.85-17.84,104.45-29.34C989.49,25,1113-14.29,1200,52.47V0Z"
            opacity=".25" class="shape-fill"></path>
        <path
            d="M0,0V15.81C13,36.92,27.64,56.86,47.69,72.05,99.41,111.27,165,111,224.58,91.58c31.15-10.15,60.09-26.07,89.67-39.8,40.92-19,84.73-46,130.83-49.67,36.26-2.85,70.9,9.42,98.6,31.56,31.77,25.39,62.32,62,103.63,73,40.44,10.79,81.35-6.69,119.13-24.28s75.16-39,116.92-43.05c59.73-5.85,113.28,22.88,168.9,38.84,30.2,8.66,59,6.17,87.09-7.5,22.43-10.89,48-26.93,60.65-49.24V0Z"
            opacity=".5" class="shape-fill"></path>
        <path
            d="M0,0V5.63C149.93,59,314.09,71.32,475.83,42.57c43-7.64,84.23-20.12,127.61-26.46,59-8.63,112.48,12.24,165.56,35.4C827.93,77.22,886,95.24,951.2,90c86.53-7,172.46-45.71,248.8-84.81V0Z"
            class="shape-fill"></path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

**toolbar-menu.component.html**

```
<div>
    <mat-toolbar color="accent" *ngIf = currentUser>
        <div fxShow="true" fxHide.gt-sm="true">
            <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
                <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </div>
        <img fxShow="false" fxHide.gt-sm="true" class="iconLogo" style="width: 5%;" src="../../../../assets/LogoCedupBranca-02.png" alt="Logo">
        <a mat-button class="companyName" routerLink="/pages/home">
            <span>Cooper Cedup</span>
        </a>
        <span class="spacer"></span>
        <div class="panel-open" fxShow="true" fxHide.lt-md="true">
            <a mat-button routerLink="/pages/students">Alunos</a>
            <a mat-button routerLink="/pages/accountability">Prestação de Contas</a>
            <a mat-button routerLink="/pages/bills">Boletos</a>
            <a mat-button routerLink="/pages/charts">Gráficos</a>
            <button (click)="encerrarSessao()" class="exitButton" mat-icon-button aria-label="Example icon-button with a heart icon">
                <mat-icon>exit_to_app</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </div>

    </mat-toolbar>
    <mat-sidenav-container color="primary" fxFlexFill class="container" >

        <mat-sidenav color="primary" #sidenav fxLayout="column" mode="over" opened="false" fxHide.gt-sm="true">
            <div fxLayout="column">
                <a mat-button routerLink="/pages/students" (click)="sidenav.close()" >Alunos</a>
                <a mat-button routerLink="/pages/accountability" (click)="sidenav.close()">Prestação de Contas</a>
                <a mat-button routerLink="/pages/bills" (click)="sidenav.close()">Boletos</a>
                <a mat-button routerLink="/pages/charts" (click)="sidenav.close()">Gráficos</a>
                <a mat-raised-button color="warn" routerLink="/login" (click)="encerrarSessao()">Logout</a>
            </div>
        </mat-sidenav>
        <mat-sidenav-content fxFlexFill>
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </mat-sidenav-content>
        
    </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-toolbar-menu >
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</app-toolbar-menu>
```

**IMAGES OF THE APPLICATION**
[How it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4FP8.png)

[How it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWiXj.png)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It looks like the css of the toolbar is styling your page (probably something like min-height and text-align). So I assume that as soon as you remove the toolbar the css that styles the page is gone as well. Try to look into the css that styles your page when the toolbar is shown and add it to your login.component.css instead.

Answer (score 0):

I understood that You are trying to change the layout based on whether user is logged in or not.

some way to do this is by having two Layouts like follows

`BaseLayoutComponent`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-base-layout',
    template: `
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `
})
export class BaseLayoutComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

}
```

`SiteLayoutComponent`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-site-layout',
    template: `
        <app-header></app-header>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `
})
export class SiteLayoutComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

}
```

and you change switch them in your `app-routing.module.ts` like this

```
const routes: Routes = [{
        path: '',
        component: SiteLayoutComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '',
        component: BaseLayoutComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'auth',
                loadChildren: () => import('./auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule),
                canActivate: [NotLoggedInGuard]
            }
        ]
    },
    
];
```

- the `NotLoggedInGuard` just check if user is not logged in